# InDesign to JPEG Font Rendering issue

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, jpg

I'm trying to export my InDesign file to jpg, but the Helvetica Neue Bold font is not rendering properly. Even tried creating pdf first and then exporting from Acrobat to jpg. Tried different resolutions (96, 100, 150). Any advice? Mac OS El Capitan.

Comment: What does "not rendering properly" mean?

Comment: Hi user101933, Welcome to graphicdesign.stackexchange. When you say that your type is not rendered properly, can you be more explicit or enclose a screen shot that shows us what you mean?

Comment: Hi. Of course. Can't send a screen shot at the moment, but certain letters and numbers are rendering either too large or too small — completely out of proportion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is causing the font issue, but here are two things to try to get an optimum JPEG without rendering issues:

1. Export your InDesign doc as an EPS (rather than PDF) and open the EPS file directly in Photoshop (right click, Open With… Adobe Photoshop). Alternatively you can try to open your PDF with Photoshop and save as a JPG, rather than exporting the PDF to JPEG.
2. Convert the font that is having issues to outlines (Type > Create Outlines) and then export to JPEG in a higher resolution.

Comment: Thank you! Both methods worked to get the font to render properly. Resolution was not the issue in my original query, (although the 150ppi jpgs are always blurred in my email viewer but not in PS or Preview). Again, very much appreciated!

Comment: Great @user101933, glad it worked. Please consider giving the answer an upvote and marking it correct if it solved your problem.

Comment: Evidently, user101933 forgot to thank you so I will.

Comment: Evidently, @Stan didn't see my thank-you (which was actually sent 8 hours earlier) and felt the need to jump on it. This is my first time using a question/answer forum but it's obvious some users are on them all day and night, just waiting to pounce on other users.

Comment: @user101933 I did note the thank you; but, was reacting to the request for an upvote from you (still lacking, BTW) by ispaany who made the effort to promptly answer your request for help. I do regret my sarcastic comment.

Comment: No problem. I only saw/see "Evidently, user101933 forgot to thank you...". I did also try to give an up vote but was getting the message that the "action requires 15 reputation" and, since this query was my very first time on stackexchange, I obviously don't have that.

Comment: But thank you for pointing out that the up vote is still lacking, b/c that is really going to make a difference (sorry, that was MY sarcastic comment). Will leave now.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the problem this is an educated guess, but I am going to assume that this rendering issue is on paragraph text (i.e. small text at 10-12pt)

What I think is happening here is that due to the relatively low resolution that the OP is exporting in (>=150dpi) the characters are only a few pixels across. 
When this happens the jpeg rendering engine ends up having to interpolate where a character edge "spills" very slightly into another pixel. 
When this happens you end up with a "false" pixel(s) making the character look bloated.

Solution: render at 300dpi+

I see this quite regularly with lower case "L" when exported to pdf, when viewing it the pdf reader engine struggles to display is properly, but it prints fine - not the same but a similar cause.

Comment: Thanks @DigitalLightcraft, but I don't think it was a resolution issue. I had the problem with different letters/numbers, which varied depending on font size chosen (all between 17 and 24 pt). The answer provided by ispaany proved most successful and I was able to get perfect rendering in the 100ppi jpeg. Thanks again!